# MYSQL query from input (datetime_local) field

Tags: php, mysql, input

I've got a problem with mysql query:

```
$req=mysql_query("
  SELECT Device_Type, Device_Number, sum(Ok) as Ok, sum(Rejected) as Rejected, sum(QC_Rejected) as QC_Rejected
  FROM `Iteration_TotalStats`
  where Line_Id = $line and Device_Number IN ($dev) and time > '$datest' and time < '$daten'
");
```

variables into "for" loop:

- $datest=$_POST['date_start'];
- $daten=$_POST['date_end '];

all works fine except time parameters with variable (`$dates` and `$datee`). 
Inputs here:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="date_start" value="2016-04-19T09:00"></input>
<input type="datetime-local" name="date_end" value="2016-04-19T21:00"></input>
```

but when i type this date and time format direct in the mysql query like this:

```
time > '2016-04-19T09:00' and time < '2016-04-19T21:00'
```

it works fine. I have no idea why it doesn't work with variable. Please help.

Comment: Please **don't** use `mysql` functions anymore. Your code is wide open to sql injection. You should really work with PDO and prepared statements! http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you for advice. I'm gonna rewrite it soon.

Comment: can you echo your request once built please ? What does it look like then ?

Comment: @Stan, echo $datest render: 2016-04-19T09:00

Answer (score 0):

Just to put you on the richt track, and to show that PDO isn't that hard once you get used to it, I went ahead and converted your code to PDO:

```
$qry = $db->prepare(
    'SELECT '
        . 'Device_Type, '
        . 'Device_Number, '
        . 'sum(Ok) as Ok, '
        . 'sum(Rejected) as Rejected, '
        . 'sum(QC_Rejected) as QC_Rejected '
    . 'FROM `Iteration_TotalStats` '
    . 'WHERE Line_Id = :line '
        . 'AND Device_Number IN ($dev) '
        . 'AND time > :start '
        . 'AND time < :end'
);

$qry->bindParam(':line', $line);
$qry->bindParam(':start', $_POST['date_start']);
$qry->bindParam(':end', $_POST['date_end']);

$result = $qry->execute();
```

You'll have to instantiate that `$db` variable first obviously, but that is just a PDO instance, which should be clear from the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Let me know if this solves your problem. And do feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: The same thing it doesn't show anything. print_r($qry) shows: PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT Device_Type, Device_Number, sum(Ok) as Ok, sum(Rejected) as Rejected, sum(QC_Rejected) as QC_Rejected FROM `Iteration_TotalStats` WHERE Line_Id = :line AND Device_Number IN (:devn) AND time > :start AND time < :end ) but with previous code (when i typed manualy date and time it works).

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i found a sulution.
In mysql query if made like this:

```
  SELECT Device_Type, Device_Number, sum(Ok) as Ok, sum(Rejected) as Rejected, sum(QC_Rejected) as QC_Rejected, DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i') 
FROM `Iteration_TotalStats` where Line_Id = $line and Device_Number IN ($dev) and time > '$ds' and time < '$de'
```

And now i use mysqli withoun bind and it's work fine.